# Create CIFS user permissions in windows via command line

Tags: windows, permissions, cmd

This is the sequence of steps I am trying to do, but from the command line instead of through the Windows GUI interfaces.

1. Browse to a network location (say, 10.126.51.20) and log in to a share (named 'myshare') with login credentials localuser/localpassword. I can do this with the command: "net use \\10.126.51.20\myshare localpassword /user:localuser"
2. Right click on 'myshare', go in to Properties/Security.
3. I see "Everyone", "Root", and "Root Group" under 'Group or user names'. I click the "Edit" button.
4. The object name listed is "\\10.126.51.20\myshare". I click "Add" to add new permissions.
5. I enter a new object name, "localuser", from the location "10.126.51.20". I click "Check Names" and "localuser" (in the field) becomes "10.126.51.20\localuser". Click "OK"
6. "localuser" now appears in the "Group or user names" field. I set the permissions for that user to "Full Control" (hit the check box). Hit "Apply" and "OK".

I am lost on how to do this from the command line. I can modify existing permissions (I've been doing it for "Everyone") using Icacls, but cannot figure how to create new permissions as described above.

The command I am using for Icacls is:

Icacls \\10.126.51.20\myshare /grant:r "Everyone":(OI)(CI)F